# what should i do when installing mod_wsgi i lost ap_config.h

Tags: apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

Can anybody tell me what's the content in this file(ap_config.h)，i want to create this file by myself,but i don't know what's the content in it.please help me ,thks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSchh.png)

Comment: Check https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/196

Comment: What platform are you using and what Apache distribution? Some Apache distributions, for Windows especially, are incomplete. On Windows use the ApacheLounge distribution. You can't just recreate the file. If that file is missing then lots others are going to be as well.

Comment: i using windows,apache 24 and python 2.7.what should i do ,if i want to use apache + mod_wsgi ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ApacheLounge that includes the header.

Comment: Thanks very much.Maybe it works,but i have already tried my best to find this file in ApacheLounge.But i can't find it,and when i wanted to use 'search' ,the webpage didn't show Search Blank to me.